# GUI app with redirected stdout stream doesn't return control back to the console

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application

I have a GUI Windows application written in C++ (with MFC) that attaches itself to a parent console for an output via `stdout` stream. It uses the [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API and the `RedirectIOToConsole` method [described here](http://dslweb.nwnexus.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm).

So if I call the following line from a regular console application (that natively has the output to stdout):

```
_tprintf(_T("Test message.\n"));
```

I get this output that I'd expect:

[image]

But if I call the same line of code from my GUI app (with an attached parent console) I get the following, except that the control doesn't seem to be returned back to the parent command prompt window (see red circle):

[image]

Note that I can type into the parent command prompt window, so it's not hanging, and if I hit enter it will execute whatever I typed as a command.

So what have I not called from my console app to return control back to the parent console?

Answer (score 1):

It's not about returning control.

When you run a console application from a command prompt the command prompt waits until the console application finishes, so you see the output from the console application followed by a fresh prompt, as your first picture shows.

When you run a GUI application from a command prompt the command prompt doesn't wait for the GUI application to finish, so you normally see a fresh prompt followed by the output from the GUI application, like this:

`C:\>TestGuiProjWithOutputToConsole`
`C:\>Test Message.`
`_`

As you've noted, nothing has gone wrong.  You can type commands and they work, it's just that the prompt has appeared in the wrong place.

Your second example doesn't show the second prompt, maybe because you've got a carriage-return character so the prompt is being overwritten.  Try outputting a newline before the test message and you should see the prompt (though still in the wrong place).

You can tell the console to wait for a GUI application by running:

`start /wait TestGuiProjWithOutputToConsole`

In short, GUI applications don't play well with the command-prompt because they are both running at the same time outputting to the same console so their output is jumbled up.

Comment: The issue happens when I run my program from an ASP script by using `WScript.Shell` object and the `Exec` method. It seems like it waits for the `Enter` after my GUI app finishes outputting data to `stdout` stream for it. I'm not sure why that happens?

Comment: `Exec` returns control to your code.  Presumably you're written some code to process the output from your gui app, and it's this code that's blocking but without seeing any of your code I'm in the dark.  What I would do first is check that the lines of output (especially the last one) from the GUI app are properly terminated with a carriage return and a line feed.  Redirect the output to a file (e.g. `guiapp > output.txt`), do a hex dump of output.txt and check that each line is terminated with "\x0d\x0a".

Comment: I think it does only `\x0a`, is `\x0d` important?

Comment: Normally your code would only explicitly write the \x0a (i.e. "\n") but this would be converted to "\x0d\x0a" by the output stream being in text mode.  The easiest way to be sure of what's happening is to spend a few seconds looking at a hex dump.  Some code is really fussy about line endings and some code isn't.  Since I don't know what you're doing with the data I don't know if it matters.  I thought this might be a problem because the second image in the question implied malformed line endings and you also said it was waiting for an Enter.